# How to fix errno 71 whilst installing laravel webpack?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, homestead

I am new to setting up a dev box with **homestead** and want to enable **laravel webpack**. According to the documentation I will need to run `"npm install"`, after running the command, I receive multiple errors, after which the wizard closes.

The console produces the following error message:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fse                                 vents): 
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@                                 1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js'                                  -> '/home/vagrant/code/jvg/node_modules/.bin/parser'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-02-08T14_45_44_822Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does `npm install --no-bin-links` work? See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9901.

Comment: It installs the packages, but after running npm run dev, the following errors are outputted:[pastbin](https://pastebin.com/Fhgt0UaA)

Answer (score 1):

Running CLI as administrator solves the problem.
Don't forget to "vagrant destroy", "vagrant up".